# On scoping of variables in c++ standard library containers

Tags: c++

Consider the following functions with questions in comments:

```
map<vector<a>, b> func() {
    map<vector<a>, b> x;
    //add values of to x.
    return x;    //Everything gets copied and the local variable dies. Not good when your x is very big, lets say in MB s
}

map<vector<a>, b> *func() {
    map<vector<a>, b> *x;
    x = new map<vector<a>, b>(); //allocate the object.
    b _b;
    a random;
    vector<a> y;
    y.push_back(random);
    //add values of to x.
    x->insert(make_pair(y, _b));
    return x;    //Pointer is returned. Not sure what would happen to keys of map. Will they be copied again?
}
```

Another question I have about above map is what would happen to the complexity of `find()`? I think it should be the same as the default comparator of vector would be used to order the elements accordingly. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
map<vector<a> *, b> *func() {
    map<vector<a>, b> *x;
    x = new map<vector<a> *, b>(); //allocate the object.
    b b_;
    a random;
    vector<a> *y = vector<a>();
    y->push_back(random);
    //add values of to x.
    x->insert(make_pair(y, b_));
    return x;    //Pointer is returned. Not sure what would happen to the elements of the keys of the map. 
                 //In other words I mean will variable 'random' be copied again on function return. Will they be copied again?
}
```

Comment: Read the [tag:STL] tag wiki before using it next time.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting *premature optimization* leading to potential disaster.

`return x`, if the compiler optimization are "on" (use the `-O3` flag on the compiler) and the compiler is not a complete dumb, will NOT result in a copy. Simply `x` will be allocated into the caller stack space and referenced inside the function.

You second attempt (returning a pointer) works, but creates problems to proper control resource allocation: you call `new` inside the function, but who and when should call `delete`?  Probably the uses of a smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr`) would help:  the created map will be deleted when no one will store anymore that pointer.

Your third attempt simply cannot work.

`vector<a> *y = vector<a>();` will even not compile (assign a `vector<a>` to a `vector<a>*` ?!?), and then, the map will contain... pointers as keys. Unless you don't provide a comparison function, the map will be sorted ... by vector's addresses and not content! And no one will take care of their destruction.

You also open another risk: since the map contain pointers as keys, no one grants for vector's const-ness: what happen to the correctness of the map sort order if the "keys" are altered under the hood by some mistakes out of that function?

Comment: I know this is a disaster. Made this mistake once. But wanted to know, just how big.

Comment: Just a side note: Some compilers, notably VC++ <=2010, perform copy elision even when optimizations are turned off. In fact, for VC++ 2010, there is no way to prevent copy elision and it is even performed when compiling in debug mode.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Even bigger than the biggest you can imagine: you allocate resources and let them exist completely out of any kind of control...  If all of this happen in a closed small group of function under your full responsibility may work. Otherwise there is no way to know.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I realized it after implementing which kind of led to this question among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt leads to copying , but the compiler will do the nasty work of optimizing and this is probably the most common of them all. There will not be copying , but just to be certain you can write:

```
std::map<std::vector<a>,b> func() {
   return map<vector<a>, b>() ;
}
```

The second attempt leads your object created on the heap . The objects placed inside the container are copied inside in

```
x->insert(make_pair(y,b));
```

and therefore their lifetime is bound to the lifetime of the container.

You are then responsible for deleting the map calling delete on the pointer, not the best practice ever, but you will see that around happening.

The complexity of find is logarithmic when you call the map member function, and linear if you call the static version on the object. There will be at most linear comparisons on your key which is a vector.

The third attempt that you work with a pointer to a vector ( needs new in )

```
std::vector<a> * y = new vector<a>;
```

and basically here you should modify your keys as well in the map to

```
std::map<vector<a> *, b>
```

needs you to modify the signature of func() to return the type appropriately.

or dereference the object in order to copy it

```
x->insert(make_pair(*y,_n));
```

The result would be that you would also have to manage the memory used for the keys and delete them one by one as need. Really beats the purpose, just try to work as much as possible with the container logic that manages automatically the memory for you.